# Recurring generic error message Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

EDIT: Not sure if this matters but I am using G Suite for Nonprofits.END EDIT:::

I keep getting this error message upon attempting to manually run this script for the first time:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 2, file "Code")).

I have saved it and authorized its permissions already. I am simply trying to execute the script to get all of the existing responses' edit URLs.

There are no triggers associated with this. The script is intended to get the edit response URLs from a Google Form. "Edit after submit" is enabled in the Form, and it is set to public in regards to who can complete the form (not that this should matter since I am the owner of the form).

I use this script in this exact form on many other projects with no issues at all. I have also tried a different script for this task that I know works, with the same error message returned. The error message always references the line of code with the form ID/URL. I have verified the form ID. Thanks for your help.

```
function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('some id');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 6;
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
    resultUrls.push([data[j][0] ?
      urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))] : ''
    ]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);
}
```

Comment: Double check that you are using the "right" form id. If you need further help describe how do you get it.

Comment: @Rubén, is there a different Form ID other than the obvious one in the URL? I do seem to remember having to find an alternate Form ID of some kind several months ago for a different script but now I can't recall how or why that was necessary.

Comment: @I'-'I You may actually be correct about this. I have had errors before that were only solved by doing this.

Comment: There are several URLs (edit, view, share, etc.) and not all of them show the same id

Comment: @Rubén Wow, you were right. That worked. I thought I was using the Form ID from the edit URL. Turns out I somehow used the Form ID from the view URL. I knew the URLs were different but I have never even noticed that the IDs change as well. Problem SOLVED. Thank you so very much.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Rubén, I was able to solve my problem. In my script I was using the incorrect Form ID. When running a script to obtain the edit response URLs from a Google Form you must view the edit form URL in the editing mode of your specific form. Extract the Form ID from this edit URL NOT the view URL or share URL etc. This is the only way your script will access the correct form with the correct permissions. Thanks again to Rubén and all others who assisted.